# Are Only + Number Adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, numbers, only

In the sentence "Only eight apples grew on the tree."  Are both "only" and "eight" adjectives?

Answer (score 2):

By nature of the sentence, "eight" is a quantitative **adjective** describing how many apples are on the tree.

On the other hand, "only" is an **adverb** describing the exclusivity of the eight apples being the only apples on the tree. It modifies the adjective, "eight".